# puphpet failes to install packages

Tags: linux, vagrant, puphpet

I'm new to puphpet and I'm tring to deploy a machine with the following config file:

```
vagrantfile:
target: local
vm:
    provider:
        local:
            box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
            box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
            box_version: '0'
            chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
            virtualizers:
                virtualbox:
                    modifyvm:
                        natdnshostresolver1: false
                    showgui: 0
            machines:
                vflm_iuacklmx1q1l:
                    id: roes
                    hostname: roes.puphpet
                    network:
                        private_network: 192.168.50.101
                        forwarded_port:
                            vflmnfp_f8witajbpcdk:
                                host: '80'
                                guest: '80'
                    memory: '3072'
                    cpus: '3'
    provision:
        puppet:
            manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
            module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
            options:
                - '--verbose'
                - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
    synced_folder:
        vflsf_c0lu72vfwayv:
            source: 'C:\Users\Jelle\symfony\VrijwilligersTool'
            target: /var/www/VrijwilligersTool
            sync_type: default
            smb:
                smb_host: ''
                smb_username: ''
                smb_password: ''
                mount_options:
                    dir_mode: '0775'
                    file_mode: '0664'
            rsync:
                args:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--archive'
                    - '-z'
                exclude:
                    - .vagrant/
                    - .git/
                auto: 'true'
            owner: www-data
            group: www-data
    usable_port_range:
        start: 10200
        stop: 10500
    post_up_message: ''
ssh:
    host: 'false'
    port: 'false'
    private_key_path: 'false'
    username: vagrant
    guest_port: 'false'
    keep_alive: '1'
    forward_agent: 'false'
    forward_x11: 'false'
    shell: 'bash -l'
    insert_key: 'false'
vagrant:
    host: detect
proxy:
    http: ''
    https: ''
    ftp: ''
    no_proxy: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: nl_BE.UTF-8
        locales:
            - nl_BE.UTF-8
        timezone: Europe/Brussels
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '1'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.7'
        root_password: secret
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_rw5biplek6za:
            name: homestead
            password: secret
    databases:
        mysqlnd_osndwm6tnrw5:
            name: homestead
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_j4jxg3loo0o1:
            user: homestead
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 2.3.1
        java_install: true
    instances:
        esi_cygoi2r38jmu:
            name: es-01
```

When is execute `vagrant up` I'm getting a sea of errors.

Normally I'd go through them all but this is a very niche thing to google and I'm totally new to this. Can someone help me out and show me my mistakes?

log file: http://pastebin.com/YK65A7zR

Comment: the best place for questions and issues about puphpet is the github issue tracker: https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues